# Plugin IntelliJ Java automatically create code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, automation

In this example ***increment()*** is invoked 2 times.

Question: does there exist some plugin, say for IntelliJ, where I could just take this line of code
with a.increment().increment(); and replace it with the following line:
a.increment().increment()..1000..times..increment(); // where thus ***increment()*** is invoked 1000 times?

```
 public class A {
       int a=0;
       A increment() {
           a++;
           return this;
       }

    }
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.increment().increment();  // increment is invoked 2 times but I need 1000 times
    }
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this `a.increment().increment()..1000..times..increment();` ??

Comment: because this question is related to my study of Lisp macros and probably (I am not sure yet) to Scala macros

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such plugin. Are you sure what you're doing is correct?  Still not convinced why you'd need to do something like `a.increment().increment()..1000..times..increment()`

Comment: I am pretty sure no such plugin exists, because the use case is pretty obscure and it could be done with a simple loop. It sounds like a really bad idea btw.

Comment: Why do you need 1000 calls to increment to study an effect? This might be a sign of an xy problem. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question.

If you actually want to write that line 1000 times (I won't ask what are the dark reasons behind that), I don't know of any plugin that does that, but you can actually help yourself with a tool like Notepad++ and just copy&paste the result from there.

To do so in Notepad++, just copy `.increment()`, click `start recording` button on top, paste it, click `stop recording`, select `Run a Macro Multiple Times`, select 1000 times, click Run and voila.

---

Now if you just want to run that 1k times and you don't mind if your code looks nice, you can put your code in any sort of loop.

At a very basic level:

```
public class A {
   int a=0;
   A increment() {
       a++;
       return this;
   }
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    A a = new A();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000) {
        a.increment();
        i++;
    }
}
```